# wget with both output-document and directory-prefix options doesn't work, however curl works fine,?

Tags: curl, wget

wget --output-document=Node.png "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9950313?s=48&v=4" --directory-prefix="public/images" doesn't work together **before creating the folder public/images**.

NB:
wget --output-document works
wget --directory-prefix works
But, not together.

However, curl works fine *before creating the folder public/images*: curl --output Node.png "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9950313?s=48&v=4" --create-dirs --output-dir public/images

What's up with the aforementioned wget command?

**Please Note**: This question is about programming (shell) indeed.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options), this probably shouldn't work (although, debatable).

> ‘-O file’ ‘--output-document=file’
>
> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file. If ‘-’ is used
> as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
> conversion. (Use ‘./-’ to print to a file literally named ‘-’.)
>
> Use of ‘-O’ is not intended to mean simply “use the name file instead of the one in the URL;” rather, it is analogous to shell
> redirection: ‘wget -O file http://foo’ is intended to work like ‘wget
> -O - http://foo > file’; file will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.
>
> For this reason, ‘-N’ (for timestamp-checking) is not supported in combination with ‘-O’: since file is always newly created, it will
> always have a very new timestamp. A warning will be issued if this
> combination is used.
>
> Similarly, using ‘-r’ or ‘-p’ with ‘-O’ may not work as you expect: Wget won’t just download the first file to file and then
> download the rest to their normal names: all downloaded content will
> be placed in file. This was disabled in version 1.11, but has been
> reinstated (with a warning) in 1.11.2, as there are some cases where
> this behavior can actually have some use.
>
> A combination with ‘-nc’ is only accepted if the given output file does not exist.
>
> Note that a combination with ‘-k’ is only permitted when downloading a single document, as in that case it will just convert
> all relative URIs to external ones; ‘-k’ makes no sense for multiple
> URIs when they’re all being downloaded to a single file; ‘-k’ can be
> used only when the output is a regular file.

As a workaround, you can use this command:

```
wget --secure-protocol=auto https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9950313?s=48&v=4" -O - > public/images/Node.png
```